# Error with processAlgorithm

Tags: pyqgis

I am preparing a procedure with QGIS that can also work as a python script both in the QGIS python console and in a standalone procedure. The procedure works in the QGIS graphical modeler but not in the QGIS python console. The line that generate the error is after `#ERROR WITH NETX LINE`

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterDefinition
import processing


class Intsec(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        param = QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('alfog', 'AL_FOG', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry], defaultValue=None)
        param.setFlags(param.flags() | QgsProcessingParameterDefinition.FlagAdvanced)
        self.addParameter(param)
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Aaaaaa', 'AAAAAA', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Bbb', 'BBB', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Ccc', 'CCC', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Al_fogInt', 'AL_FOG INT', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue='G:/R/Procedure/Fogli/Files Fogli/AL_FOG INT.shp'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination('Inyt', 'INYT', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

  #ERROR WITH NETX LINE
  def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(5, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Polygon self-intersection
        alg_params = {
            'ID': 'Nomefile',
            'POLYGONS': parameters['alfog'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['Inyt']
        }
        outputs['PolygonSelfintersection'] = processing.run('saga:polygonselfintersection', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Inyt'] = outputs['PolygonSelfintersection']['INTERSECT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract by attribute
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD': 'OBJECTID',
            'INPUT': outputs['PolygonSelfintersection']['INTERSECT'],
            'OPERATOR': 0,
            'VALUE': '0',
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Aaaaaa']
        }
        outputs['ExtractByAttribute'] = processing.run('native:extractbyattribute', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Aaaaaa'] = outputs['ExtractByAttribute']['OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Ripara geometrie
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractByAttribute']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Bbb']
        }
        outputs['RiparaGeometrie'] = processing.run('native:fixgeometries', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Bbb'] = outputs['RiparaGeometrie']['OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Aggiungi attributi della geometria
        alg_params = {
            'CALC_METHOD': 0,
            'INPUT': outputs['RiparaGeometrie']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Ccc']
        }
        outputs['AggiungiAttributiDellaGeometria'] = processing.run('qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Ccc'] = outputs['AggiungiAttributiDellaGeometria']['OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Aggiungi attributi della geometria
        alg_params = {
            'CALC_METHOD': 2,
            'INPUT': outputs['AggiungiAttributiDellaGeometria']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Al_fogInt']
        }
        outputs['AggiungiAttributiDellaGeometria'] = processing.run('qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Al_fogInt'] = outputs['AggiungiAttributiDellaGeometria']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'INTSEC'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'INTSEC'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Intsec()
```

---

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource

    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 168, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 99, in _maybe_compile
    raise err1

  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 87, in _maybe_compile
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)


  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 133, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
  File "<input>", line 10
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Add two more leading spaces to `def processAlgorithm`. It should be four spaces before `def processAlgorithm`.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it doesn't depend on it

Comment: It looks like an indentation error.

Comment: You are right but i don't know how to correct it

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterDefinition
import processing


class Intsec(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        param = QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('alfog', 'AL_FOG', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry], defaultValue=None)
        param.setFlags(param.flags() | QgsProcessingParameterDefinition.FlagAdvanced)
        self.addParameter(param)
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Aaaaaa', 'AAAAAA', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Bbb', 'BBB', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Ccc', 'CCC', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Al_fogInt', 'AL_FOG INT', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue='G:/R/Procedure/Fogli/Files Fogli/AL_FOG INT.shp'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination('Inyt', 'INYT', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(5, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Polygon self-intersection
        alg_params = {
            'ID': 'Nomefile',
            'POLYGONS': parameters['alfog'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['Inyt']
        }
        outputs['PolygonSelfintersection'] = processing.run('saga:polygonselfintersection', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Inyt'] = outputs['PolygonSelfintersection']['INTERSECT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract by attribute
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD': 'OBJECTID',
            'INPUT': outputs['PolygonSelfintersection']['INTERSECT'],
            'OPERATOR': 0,
            'VALUE': '0',
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Aaaaaa']
        }
        outputs['ExtractByAttribute'] = processing.run('native:extractbyattribute', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Aaaaaa'] = outputs['ExtractByAttribute']['OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Ripara geometrie
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractByAttribute']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Bbb']
        }
        outputs['RiparaGeometrie'] = processing.run('native:fixgeometries', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Bbb'] = outputs['RiparaGeometrie']['OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Aggiungi attributi della geometria
        alg_params = {
            'CALC_METHOD': 0,
            'INPUT': outputs['RiparaGeometrie']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Ccc']
        }
        outputs['AggiungiAttributiDellaGeometria'] = processing.run('qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Ccc'] = outputs['AggiungiAttributiDellaGeometria']['OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Aggiungi attributi della geometria
        alg_params = {
            'CALC_METHOD': 2,
            'INPUT': outputs['AggiungiAttributiDellaGeometria']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Al_fogInt']
        }
        outputs['AggiungiAttributiDellaGeometria'] = processing.run('qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Al_fogInt'] = outputs['AggiungiAttributiDellaGeometria']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'INTSEC'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'INTSEC'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Intsec()
```